# Rebass modal not showing when state is changed. Why is it not passing true?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog

The modal is not showing even though I passed a boolean of true attribute to function. It seems that SuccessModal turns true but Overlay does not.
How come it's not working?

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import {
  Overlay,
  Panel,
  PanelHeader,
  PanelFooter,
  Button,
  Text,
  //Close,
  Space
} from 'rebass';

function SuccessModal ({modalOpen}) {

    return (
    <Overlay
      open={modalOpen}
    >
      <Panel theme="success">
        <PanelHeader>
          Wicckkkeedd!
          <Space auto />
        />
        </PanelHeader>
        <img
          src='http://lorempixel.com/512/384/cats'
          style={{
              maxWidth: '100%',
              height: 'auto'
          }} />
        <Text>
          <b>Panel:</b> Something laid as a covering something else
        </Text>
        <PanelFooter>
          <Space auto />
          <Button
            theme='success'
            children='Meow!' 
          />
        </PanelFooter>
      </Panel>
    </Overlay>
  );
}


export default SuccessModal;
```

If you need more code to debug please let me know!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This works by accessing props children.

import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
    import {
      Overlay,
      Panel,
      PanelHeader,
      PanelFooter,
      Button,
      Text,
      //Close,
      Space
    } from 'rebass';

```
function SuccessModal ({modalOpen}) {

    return (
    <Overlay
      open={modalOpen.open}
    >
      <Panel theme="success">
        <PanelHeader>
          Wicckkkeedd!
          <Space auto />
        />
        </PanelHeader>
        <img
          src='http://lorempixel.com/512/384/cats'
          style={{
              maxWidth: '100%',
              height: 'auto'
          }} />
        <Text>
          <b>Panel:</b> Something laid as a covering something else
        </Text>
        <PanelFooter>
          <Space auto />
          <Button
            theme='success'
            children='Meow!' 
          />
        </PanelFooter>
      </Panel>
    </Overlay>
  );
}


export default SuccessModal;
```